# Focus next element using onKeyDown

Tags: reactjs, tabindex

I'm looping through a list of elements in React, and displaying them in a grid.  I want to be able to navigate the grid using the keyboard.

This function renders the grid:

```
listOfEmployees() {
    const results = [];
    while (this.state.filteredView.length) {
      results.push(this.state.filteredView.splice(0, 3))
    }
    return results.map(result =>
      <Row
        style={{display: 'contents'}}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        {result.map(e =>
          <Col sm={4}>
            <Link
              to={`/employee/${e.id}`}
              style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}}
              className="Link"
            >
              <Wrapper>
                <Name>
                  {e.name}
                </Name>
                <JobTitle>
                  {e.job_titles}
                </JobTitle>
              </Wrapper>
            </Link>
          </Col>
        )}
      </Row>
    )
  }
```

And here is my `handleKeyPress` event handler:

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    const links = document.getElementsByClassName('Link')
    let active = document.activeElement.tabIndex
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      links[1].focus()
      // links[active + 1].focus() *This does not work*
    }
  }
```

This works, but it's hardcoded, so I only get the second div focused (`links[1]`).  How do I make it dynamic so that every right arrow key press moves the focus over one div?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  I added an id to the `<Link />`, then used that value to get the next element.

```
<Link
  to={`/employee/${e.id}`}
  style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}}
  className="Link"
  id={e.id}
>
```

Then

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    const link = document.getElementsByClassName('Link')
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      const targetId = parseInt(e.target.id) - 1
      link[targetId + 1].focus()
    } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      const targetId = parseInt(e.target.id) - 1
      link[targetId - 1].focus()
    }
  }
```

Hopefully this helps someone else, too.